# How to reduce the image pixels in android?

Tags: android, image

I have an image with resolution 1920X1080 pixels of resolution.I want to change its resolution to 300X300.

[I have tried this link](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html)

but it's not working.Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Get an exception? Tried to debug it to isolate the problematic line of code? Please add some more details, your question is pretty vague.

Comment: the link you provide is working, no problem with the code!

Comment: "it's not working". Do I it hate when people give that much details, its overwhelming ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have your image as a Bitmap-instance just use

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 300, 300, true);
```

More info about the bitmap methods are available in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: You might also want to consider calling recycle() on the original bitmap to free its resources if you aren't going to use it after creating the scaled version.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the image in an image view like this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>
```

Good luck,
Arkde